# Disabling "cut" from excel with vba

Tags: vba, excel

I've read many threads on this topic, but the code I have found there doesn't seem to work. I am trying to disable the "cut" function from an excel spreadsheet and I would like the icon to grey out.

I have been using this code:

```
Sub WorkSheet_Activate()
Application.CommandBars.FindControl(ID:=21).Enabled = False 
End Sub
```

However, I can still use the "cut" function without any problem.... 
Also I know there are some functions that allow you to disable cut/copy/paste, but I still want copy and paste to be allowed in this spreadsheet.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Kristen

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Check the link for the reference - [Disable Cut](http://www.vbaexpress.com/kb/getarticle.php?kb_id=373)

Try something like this:

```
Option Explicit
Private Sub Workbook_SheetSelectionChange(ByVal Sh As Object, _
ByVal Target As Excel.Range)

Select Case Application.CutCopyMode
Case Is = False
'do nothing
Case Is = xlCopy
'do nothing
Case Is = xlCut
MsgBox "Please DO NOT Cut and Paste. Use Copy and Paste; then delete the source."
Application.CutCopyMode = False 'clear clipboard and cancel cut
End Select

End Sub
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: just to add that that Sub is to be place in `ThisWorkbook` code pane

Comment: @user3598756: o you are right. Thanks for pointing that. Sorry forgot to take the edit.

Comment: @RanadipDutta, it'd be better you add the sub placing issue in your answer so as to have it a complete one for future readers and not asking them for reading comments reading, which is neither granted nor (sometimes) easy. Once you should review your answer I'll remove my comment

Comment: Unfortunately this code does not stop users moving cells using drag-and-drop

Comment: @PeterSmallwood: Drag and drop is a mouseclick event. That is completely different thing that cut /paste/copy operations. OPs question was different.